# How can I have a public function to run all my PHP cURL requests?

Tags: php, curl

I have a basic RESTful API setup using cURL for all my requests.

At the moment, I am attempting to split out all my functions to have one function that runs all my requests.

For example, I have the following which can be called from `localhost/api/getUserData`

```
private function getUserData() {
     $url = 'localhost/api/users/';
     runApiCall($url);
}
```

That function then goes on to pass the URL to `runApiCall()`, which is the following:

```
function runApiCall($url) {

     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);

     $this->response($result, 200);
}
```

Although, I keep getting an error in my console of `http://localhost/api/getUserData 500 (Internal Server Error)`

The API was working perfectly fine before I split it out.

**EDIT:**

If I simply change my `getUserData()` function to the following, it works perfectly fine:

```
private function getUserData() {
     $url = 'localhost/api/users/';

     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);

     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
     curl_close($ch);
     $this->response($this->json($result), $status);
}
```

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky - Sorry mate, renamed the function for the purpose of this question. Forgot to rename it in both places. Made an edit, thanks.

Comment: Why does getUserData() have to be private? You are calling it from outside if I understand you.

Comment: Part of my RESTful service. Although being either `public` or `private` does not solve the issue.

Comment: have you tried using var_dump in the runApiCall method to see if the variable is passed correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with scope as you are inside a class.

```
private function getUserData() {
     $url = 'localhost/api/users/';
     $this->runApiCall($url); // call $this object's runAppCall() function
}
```

Comment: You're exactly right. Can't believe I missed that! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you had error handling enabled, you'd see an error thrown by PHP telling you that it could not find the method `runApiCall()`.  This is because you are inside a class and must explicitly tell PHP to run the method on the class.

You can do this by:

```
private function getUserData() {
     $url = 'localhost/api/users/';

     // EITHER
     $this->runApiCall($url); 

     // OR
     self::runApiCall($url);
}
```

In future, I'd recommend adding this line at the route of your application when you are developing, then set it to false in production:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This will now log any PHP errors to the browser, making it much easier for you to debug.